# Bootstrap div height issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want the height of the alert to be same as the height of the input field. I am unable to do that using bootstrap.

I tried putting col-mb-4 in the alert class but no luck with the height alignment.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <label for="inputCompanyName" class="col-form-label col-2">Company :</label>
    <div class="col-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCompanyName" placeholder="" formControlName="companyName" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="companyNameVal.errors?.['required'] && companyNameVal.touched">
      Company name is required!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Col-mb is not a bootstrap grid class.... 

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

Comment: Notice how I modified your code to present an example of your problem. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You're asking for an element whose height is defined by its contents to be resized, but you haven't said what you're willing to change. Do you want to remove the space around the text? Do you want to truncate the text? Please revise to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since rows are flex containers you can use `align-items-stretch` to make all child elements full height. Then you can set `h-100` on the input to also make *it* full height. Finally, remove margin from the alert so it doesn't affect the alert's height. Use padding on the row if you want to retain that space. Note that I've also reduced vertical padding on the alert with `py-1`, in case that's what you actually wanted.

The advantage here, over padding or other fixed-size solutions, is that it's fluid. It doesn't matter what height the alert element attains--the input will match.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mb-3 row align-items-stretch">
    <label for="inputCompanyName" class="col-form-label col-2">Company :</label>
    <div class="col-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control h-100" id="inputCompanyName" placeholder="" formControlName="companyName" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 alert alert-danger mb-0 py-1" role="alert" *ngIf="companyNameVal.errors?.['required'] && companyNameVal.touched">
      Company name is required!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "m-0 p-1" on alert class like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <label for="inputCompanyName" class="col-form-label col-2">Company :</label>
    
    <div class="col-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCompanyName" placeholder="" formControlName="companyName" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 alert alert-danger m-0 p-1" role="alert" *ngIf="companyNameVal.errors?.['required'] && companyNameVal.touched">
      Company name is required!
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```